# My bootstrap css and js links are not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, bootstrap-5

I have included the path of bootstrap css file and js file in the code by they are not working and i get those errors in the console:
GET [http://127.0.0.1:5000/[https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css%20%E2%86%97](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)](http://127.0.0.1:5000/%5Bhttps://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css%20%E2%86%97%5D(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)) net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
127.0.0.1/:96          GET [http://127.0.0.1:5000/[https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js%20%E2%86%97](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js)](http://127.0.0.1:5000/%5Bhttps://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js%20%E2%86%97%5D(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js)) net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)

Here is the part of the code:

```
<script src="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\CS50X\project\static\bootstrapjs/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I tried using cdn but i got the same messages also and i tried the links from the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try using a relative reference, and put the script with your project.

> <script src="./scripts/local_file.js">

or use a reference to a CDN, using the full address.

> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">

Comment: i tried using CDN for both css and js but i got 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1'

Comment: and also 'bootstrap.min.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET'